# Remember Scroll When Getting Back

Tags: angular, typescript

I`m working with angular 4(angular-router@4.4.6);
I have an instagram-like post grid and timeline, I want to to remember scroll point after getting back from a post etc,...
I use the customRouteReuseStrategy shown below, but it gives an unpredictable behaviour

Can anybody please give me a solution or alternative?
Thanks

```
private handlers: { [key: string]: DetachedRouteHandle } = {};


constructor() {

}

shouldDetach(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    return true;
}

store(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, handle: DetachedRouteHandle): void {
    this.handlers[route.url.join("/") || route.parent.url.join("/")] = handle;
}

shouldAttach(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    return !!this.handlers[route.url.join("/")];
}

retrieve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): DetachedRouteHandle {
    return this.handlers[route.url.join("/") || route.parent.url.join("/")];
}

shouldReuseRoute(future: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, curr: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    return future.routeConfig === curr.routeConfig;
}
```

Comment: this isn't a great answer, so sorry, but I use ui-router for angular 4 and when I switch between my views my scroll position is remembered.  One thing you can try to do is wrap your router outlet in a div that scrolls and then scroll using the outerdiv,   your internal content will always be in the same position you left off, but not to be confused with "each" position being individually remembered, its more of a single global div that remembers its own scroll position, so you swap a view in and out and its at the bottom both views will be at the bottom.  might be helpful as a option